# Moderators: Spam/Answers on one of my posts

Tags: support, spam, moderators

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479363/how-tell-the-difference-between-a-debit-card-and-a-credit-card) a while back. Recently, I have received two answers. The first time, it seemed spammy, but it did answer the question so I up-voted it. Now there is a second answer to the same site. Both users had a rep of 1.

- [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479363/how-tell-the-difference-between-a-debit-card-and-a-credit-card/3913768#3913768)
- [Second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479363/how-tell-the-difference-between-a-debit-card-and-a-credit-card/3957803#3957803) from today.

I just want to make you aware of this in case there is something that needs to be done to them.

Comment: Why not flag the answers for moderator attention? It's a much more direct mode of communication than posting on Meta. Or, even more direct, flag them as spam.

Comment: I guess I am questioning if it is spam. Maybe I'll just flag it anyway.

Comment: Wow, one of those answerers actually registered. And the other one has the exact same gravatar, what a coincidence.... (I flagged 'em both as spam, by the way.)

Comment: That isn't why I though that.

Comment: Yeah, it's just unusual.

Comment: If you are not yet aware, spam flags do age away if they don't accumulate enough of them. So if no one else in the community agrees that they are spam, the flags will vanish harmlessly after a couple of days.

Comment: Okay, that was more of my worry. If they are an actual user and genuinely is trying to help. I didn't want to hurt their rep for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and protected the question too; this is exactly the sort of situation it was intended for.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/

Thanks for the report!